# Как сохранить архив с acl ntfs из под linux?

Tags: linux, windows, файлы, ntfs, archive

Как скопировать файл/папку на разделе *ntfs* в архив с сохранением всех атрибутов?

При условии, что раздел смонтирован из-под *linux*. Аналог `tar -cvf --same-permissions`.

С разделами проблем нет - нужно копировать именно отдельные папки и файлы.

Comment: а в *ms/windows*-то такое возможно?

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, под Windows  rar и 7z умеют сохранять права и альтстримы NTFS(при указании соответствующего ключа). Под linux же этот функционал естественно вырезан за ненадобностью.

Возможно в самбе есть какой-то аналог ключей `/save` и `/restore` утилиты `icacls`, позволяющей сохранять/восстанавливать ntfs-атрибуты в отдельный файл - тогда архивировать вместе с правами не будет проблемой.

Comment: Это невозможно, так как драйвер NTFS под Linux [не поддерживает](http://askubuntu.com/a/301612/548598) виндовозные ACL.

Comment: @gbg, оформи пожалуйста как ответ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это невозможно, так как драйвер NTFS под Linux [не поддерживает](https://askubuntu.com/a/301612/548598) виндовозные ACL.

Answer (score 2):

ответ из комментария:

---

Под *Windows* *rar* и *7z* умеют сохранять права и альтстримы *NTFS* (при указании соответствующего ключа). Под *linux* же этот функционал, естественно, вырезан за ненадобностью.

Возможно, в самбе есть какой-то аналог ключей `/save` и `/restore` утилиты `icacls`, позволяющей сохранять/восстанавливать *ntfs-атрибуты* в отдельный файл - тогда архивировать вместе с правами не будет проблемой.

Comment: Да, я прочёл. Не уверен на счёт того, что это нигде не реализовано, потому что partclone.ntfs прекрасно сохраняет все права. Она конечно работает на блочном уровне, но всё равно.

Comment: @donRumata, я думаю, именно потому, что «работает на блочном устройстве». у вас в вопросе, собственно, об этом упоминается.